# Assigning PWD last value to variable in perl module

Tags: perl, variable-assignment, perl-module

i wanted to assign to variable `$run` in perl module and to have check in if condition.
Basically the `$run` variable is assigned with last value of the current working directory and in if condition if the perl script is checking with value assigned with variable `$run`

part of perl module code script snippet where exact issue has been seen.

```
ex.pm
-----
 my $run = ${PWD##*/};
  if ( $2 ne $run)
  {
    die "$0 should be run in a $run directory.";
  }
```

with this code i am getting compilation issue. same thing if directly have if condition with last path value hardcoded its working good `if ( $2 ne '4')`.

compilation issue messages

```
syntax error at bin/ex.pm line 44, near ")
  {"
syntax error at bin/ex.pm line 49, near "$sitepath "
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at bin/TestConstants.pm line 72.
Compilation failed in require at bin/ex1.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bin/ex1.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require at ./bin/test.pl line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./bin/test.pl line 26 (#1)
    (F) Probably means you had a syntax error.  Common reasons include:

        A keyword is misspelled.
        A semicolon is missing.
        A comma is missing.
        An opening or closing parenthesis is missing.
        An opening or closing brace is missing.
        A closing quote is missing.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use bash syntax in Perl.

```
$run = ${PWD##*/};
```

The right hand side is a bash way of saying "Remove everything up to the last slash", which in Perl is written as

```
$run = $ENV{PWD} =~ s{.*/}{}r;
```

or

```
$run = substr $ENV{PWD}, 1 + rindex $ENV{PWD}, '/';
```

Comment: ```$run = $ENV{PWD} =~ s{.*/}{}r;``` here to variable $run is assigned with  ```$ENV{PWD}``` and  ```$ENV{PWD}``` is assigned with ```=~ s{.*/}{}r;```. is that what happening with this line? with this line addition there will be compilation issue.

Comment: No, in `$ENV{PWD}` everything up to the last `/` is substituted with an empty string and the result is assigned to `$run`.  Perl 5.14+ is needed for the `r` modifier to work (10 years old).